# Reinstall application above existing

Tags: apt, software-installation, deb

Is there a way to reinstall `.deb` file so that to keep all previously installed files in place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be via `dpkg` with a command like:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite {your .deb}
```

<sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{your .deb}` with the proper file name.</sup>

For the few times that I've needed to do this, none of the existing configuration files were modified. *However*, this may not be the case if the `.deb` insists on some configuration files being written as part of the installation. It will still be a good idea to make some selective backups before running this command.

Comment: Unfortunately this removes old files. I cannot say whether they treated as configuration or data, but it is data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
sudo apt install ./package.deb
```

The `./` or real path is mandatory here.

The default behavior is to keep configuration files if you don't have done

```
sudo apt purge package
```